# How long have you been off?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is it perfectly clear that "How long have you been off?" asks about how long Guy 1 has been on leave in this dialog? Or should I change it?

> Guy 1: I'm not working at the moment. I'm on leave.
>
> ... (later in the conversation)
>
> Guy 2: What about your job? Is it here? (in the city)
>
> Guy 1: Yes.
>
> Guy 2: **How long have you been off?**
>
> Guy 1: Four months.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Can you edit to explain a bit more about the meaning you want? The meaning would be understood as the same as "How long have you been [not working, on leave]." Is that what you want?